# c/c++ libnetfilter_queue and application layer packets selection

Tags: c++, c, linux, networking, netfilter

I've got a c++ program using [libnetfilter_queue](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/) library, designed to work on a Linux system.

I'd need to filter only application layer packets (hence, packets including payload for the application layer of the host).

I know that it's not possible with `iptables`, without rebuilding the kernel.
Since I can't do that on the final host device, I'm working from my c++ program.

My aim is to directly accept non-application layer packets and to process layer-7 packets.

I tried using the [nfq_get_payload](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/group__Parsing.html#gaf79628558c94630e25dbfcbde09f2933https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/group__Parsing.html#gaf79628558c94630e25dbfcbde09f2933) function, returning `-1` if an error (hence, I suppose, no payload) if found.

```
ret = nfq_get_payload(tb, &data);
if (ret < 0) { /* accept packet */ }
else { /* process packet */ }
```

I know that the `nfq_get_payload` function depends on the "adopted mode" (see [nfq_set_mode](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/group__Queue.html#ga91132c19732d648fe89de852d71edfff) function), but it is not working to me.

How can I discriminate between application layer packets and "lower-layers" ones?

Knowing that the `ip_src` byte location is in `data + 12` (see also [here](http://ip_src%20=%20*((uint32_t%20*)%20(buffer%20+%2012));)), since the TCP layer size is `64` bytes, the payload should be found, if available, in position `data + 12 + 64`.

```
unsigned char* pkt_payload = (buffer + 12 + 64));
```

Nevertheless, if I try to print the `pkt_payload` variable, it is not compliant to the expected results.

How can I solve it?

Comment: This is a C++ question. Why is it tagged as C?

Comment: Because the library is also working on C programs (see https://www.netfilter.org for more information). Changed post title.